# Android Room: how to query related entities without foreign key column

Tags: android, android-room

My data is organised somewhat different than you would normally expect in an SQL database, but I cannot change that. So, I have related entities in which the parent is referencing its children using an array of child IDs:

```
data class Parent(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val children: List<Int>
)

data class Child(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int
)
```

What I would like to have is a single query or DAO function that retrieves a Parent and its Children in one call. So I probably have to create a combined entity like:

```
data class ParentWithChildren(
    val parent: Parent,
    val children: List<Child>
)
```

But what is the recommended way to fetch the result (preferably as LiveData)? Is there a @Query annotation that could retrieve the result or do I have to do something like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM parent WHERE id = :id")
fun getParent(id: Int): LiveData<Parent>

@Query("SELECT * FROM child WHERE id IN (:ids)")
fun getChildren(ids: List<Int>): List<Child>

fun getParentWithChildren(id: String): LiveData<ParentWithChildren> {
    return Transformations.map(getParent(id)) { parent ->
        val children = getChildren(parent.children)
        ParentWithChildren(parent, children)
    }
}
```

Or is there even a different approach to this? Any help on how to do this the proper "Room-like" way is much appreciated.

Comment: use @Relation you can refer here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation

Comment: I don't think so. If I understand @Relation correctly, it only works as long as Child has a reference to its Parent, which is exactly my problem: it's only the parent who has references to its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for now I've solved the issue using [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData), as it seems to be the right tool for merging LiveData. So instead I've created the following (simplified) ViewModel:

```
class ParentWithChildrenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val parent: LiveData<Parent>

    val children: LiveData<List<Child>>

    val parentWithChildren = MediatorLiveData<ParentWithChildren>()

    init {
        parent = parentRepository.getParent(id)

        children = Transformations.switchMap(parent) {
            childRepository.getChildren(it.children)
        }

        with (parentWithChildren) {
            addSource(parent) { parent ->
                children.value?.let { children ->
                    value = ParentWithChildren(parent, children)
                }
            }

            addSource(children) { children ->
                parent.value?.let { parent ->
                    value = ParentWithChildren(parent, children)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and observe the `parentWithChildren` property.